# Does calling pthread_cond_wait in a thread unlock the mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Man pages say this **pthread_cond_wait atomically unlocks the mutex (as per pthread_unlock_mutex) and waits for the condition variable cond to be signaled**. 
But then thread **start_function** could be entered by any other thread causing two threads to be in the critical block.

```
    void* start_function(){
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
         // critical block
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    
    int main(){
// code to create threads
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    }
```

So in the above code after it hits pthread_cond_wait it will unlock the mutex ?

Comment: That is undefined behaviour. The mutex MUST be locked by the thread calling `pthread_cond_wait` exactly to prevent unpredictable results.

Comment: That is the whole point of unlocking, it allows others to access the resource associated with the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a condition when you create threads. In Mutual Exclusion only one process can run critical area at a time. A process remains in the critical area finite time and when it's done its work and no one process remains in the critical area then with condition signals the other thread is ready to run also this critical area. All this work is done to avoid an impasse. Also when a process stops outside of critical block it must not interact with other processes. So your example must be:

```
void* start_function(){
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
           pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
         // critical block or critical area

         // you can use signals here 
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    
    int main(){
        // code to create threads
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
             pthreaf_create(x[i],&start_function,...,NULL);
       }
    }
```

It is probably at the end of the program some pthreads  have been stuck at con_wait(), so you need a broadcast() to free all threads

Comment: So in the above code that u posted. When pthread_cond_wait gets executed. a mutex will get unlocked. and so other threads can enter the critical section? I see why my code was wrong because the thread calling the _wait should have lock on the mutex

Comment: @pensee yeah exactly.Was this helpfull to you ?

Comment: yes it was helpful. But I am not able to understand why unlock of mutex happens on pthread_cond_wait. 1) Isnt pthread_mutex_unlock function there for unlocking. <br />
2) If pthread_cond_wait() releases the lock and there is a critical section of code between **pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);**  **pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);** there could be trouble as other thread could enter into the critical section. I am probably confused. Please correct me. what you think

Comment: @pensee pthread_cond_wait  unlocks the mutex just before it sleeps (as you note), but then it reaquires the mutex (which may require waiting) when it is signalled, before it wakes up. So if the signalling thread holds the mutex (the usual case), the waiting thread will not proceed until the signalling thread also unlocks the mutex.Mutex locks the critical area but the  it maybe catch a signal and starts running also so you use cond to for that

Answer (score 0):

> Man pages say this **pthread_cond_wait atomically unlocks the mutex
> (as per pthread_unlock_mutex) and waits for the condition variable
> cond to be signaled**.

Yes, right after they say that that function

> **shall be called with mutex locked by the calling thread** or undefined behavior results.

(emphasis added).  You go on to remark,

> But then thread **start_function** could be
> entered by any other thread causing two threads to be in the critical
> block.

If you invoke undefined behavior by calling `pthread_cond_wait()` without holding the specified mutex then *anything* can happen -- the behavior is undefined.  It is possible that the undefined behavior manifests simply as two threads executing in the critical region at the same time, with whatever follow-on effects that may have, but it is also possible that the program crashes, then or later, or corrupts memory, or deadlocks, or tweets all your passwords, among a universe of possibilities.

> So in the above code after it hits pthread_cond_wait it will unlock the mutex ?

Impossible to say.  Again, the behavior is undefined.